# SSL client certificate auth using apache httpclient

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

setup:
I have generated server and client self-signed certificates.

Have added the root certificate to truststore cacert.jks.
Have added the server certificate to keystore keystore.jks.
Have added tomcat config correctly (browser works).

Have a seperate keystore client.jks for sample GET request, based on: 
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

problem:
if i point the browser to localhost:8443, I get the error: ssl_error_bad_cert_alert
I'm able to load the default page, after adding the .p12 certificate to firefox/chrome, and it lets me select the certificate to send interactively.

However, the java client call fails with:

```
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

I'm not sure if cert are being sent:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=ca@xxx.in, CN=CA Admin, OU=CA, O=local in da house, L=Bangalore, ST=Karnataka, C=IN>
*** ServerHelloDone
*** Certificate chain
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { ...}
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 77
```

and finally fails with:

```
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 231, 55, 193, 12, 126, 106, 78, 235, 72, 209, 1, 113 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, bad_certificate
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, Exception while waiting for close javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

Am I sending the correct certificate, client.jks has just one, or am I sending anything at all. Is there a way to override sending client certificate or send all certificates?

Edit: adding server debug logs:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=caadmin@caboss.org, CN=caadmin, OU=ca, O=CA Boss, L=bangalore, ST=KA, C=IN>
*** ServerHelloDone
http-bio-8443-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1476
http-bio-8443-exec-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 77
*** Certificate chain
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
http-bio-8443-exec-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate
http-bio-8443-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-8443-exec-1, called closeSocket()
http-bio-8443-exec-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
http-bio-8443-exec-1, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
http-bio-8443-exec-1, called close()
http-bio-8443-exec-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

I see from the "*** Certificate chain" is followed not by any entries like "chain[n]= ...". Does this mean no certificate is being sent from the client side?

Edit: adding serverlogs for googlechrome - as i said earlier, cert auth works when connecting from firefox / chrome.

when client certificate is not present in browser store:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=caadmin@caboss.org, CN=caadmin, OU=ca, O=CA Boss, L=bangalore, ST=KA, C=IN>
*** ServerHelloDone
http-bio-8443-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1504
http-bio-8443-exec-10, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 77
*** Certificate chain
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-8, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
http-bio-8443-exec-10, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate
http-bio-8443-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-8443-exec-10, called closeSocket()
http-bio-8443-exec-10, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
http-bio-8443-exec-10, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
http-bio-8443-exec-10, called close()
http-bio-8443-exec-10, called closeInternal(true)
```

when certificate is present in browser store:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=caadmin@caboss.org, CN=caadmin, OU=ca, O=CA Boss, L=bangalore, ST=KA, C=IN>
*** ServerHelloDone
http-bio-8443-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1504
http-bio-8443-exec-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1247
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=client@clientboss.org, CN=client, OU=clientboss, O=client boss, L=bng, ST=ka, C=in
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 28632453992003431308915057706872593510827517481645176167926299596175388758364475388282973862780043525858628044314596282467149011086426793445608130577955324107891088141707834114383829274495458679055679534162696112905173150434463742848918480552822337987796140398151985164856125750513570841056135410235400373584276647404249334190718247108789459533624236506201184258830704869791048114520941758364485115072957575259760369673257402633308683304933495211104494746578922374021151983094620317725008850265643603908594096873957992013696420211357274147343040148174076085536080587875591891218216008897086438638059125110840536055577
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue May 27 15:58:23 IST 2014,
               To: Wed May 27 15:58:23 IST 2015]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=caadmin@caboss.org, CN=caadmin, OU=ca, O=CA Boss, L=bangalore, ST=KA, C=IN
  SerialNumber: [    04]
```

Edit: got it to work
Finally got it to work: at the client side I was not registering a keystore that had the client selfsigned certificate.

```
    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            **.loadKeyMaterial(trustStore, "changeit".toCharArray())** // this is needed
            .build();
```

Post the change the client debug logs:

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<EMAILADDRESS=caadmin@caboss.org, CN=caadmin, OU=ca, O=CA Boss, L=bangalore, ST=KA, C=IN>
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 145
0000: 0D 00 00 8D 03 01 02 40   00 87 00 85 30 81 82 31  .......@....0..1
0010: 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06   13 02 49 4E 31 0B 30 09  .0...U....IN1.0.
0020: 06 03 55 04 08 0C 02 4B   41 31 12 30 10 06 03 55  ..U....KA1.0...U
0030: 04 07 0C 09 62 61 6E 67   61 6C 6F 72 65 31 10 30  ....bangalore1.0
0040: 0E 06 03 55 04 0A 0C 07   43 41 20 42 6F 73 73 31  ...U....CA Boss1
0050: 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 0B   0C 02 63 61 31 10 30 0E  .0...U....ca1.0.
0060: 06 03 55 04 03 0C 07 63   61 61 64 6D 69 6E 31 21  ..U....caadmin1!
0070: 30 1F 06 09 2A 86 48 86   F7 0D 01 09 01 16 12 63  0...*.H........c
0080: 61 61 64 6D 69 6E 40 63   61 62 6F 73 73 2E 6F 72  aadmin@caboss.or
0090: 67                                                 g
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
matching alias: client
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=client@clientboss.org, CN=client, OU=clientboss, O=client boss, L=bng, ST=ka, C=in
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 28632453992003431308915057706872593510827517481645176167926299596175388758364475388282973862780043525858628044314596282467149011086426793445608130577955324107891088141707834114383829274495458679055679534162696112905173150434463742848918480552822337987796140398151985164856125750513570841056135410235400373584276647404249334190718247108789459533624236506201184258830704869791048114520941758364485115072957575259760369673257402633308683304933495211104494746578922374021151983094620317725008850265643603908594096873957992013696420211357274147343040148174076085536080587875591891218216008897086438638059125110840536055577
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue May 27 15:58:23 IST 2014,
               To: Wed May 27 15:58:23 IST 2015]
  Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=caadmin@caboss.org, CN=caadmin, OU=ca, O=CA Boss, L=bangalore, ST=KA, C=IN
  SerialNumber: [    04]
```

Comment: You've added the root certificate to the server's cacerts.jks or the client's cacerts.jks?  And what root certificate are you talking about?  You've added the server's self signed certificate to the server's keystore.jks or the client's keystore.jks?

Comment: On the server(localhost), I have a selfcreated CA root cert. ca.crt in cacerts.jks, selfsigned server certificate in keystore.jks. Client side i have just the selfsigned client certificate in the client.jks.

Comment: I am stuck in the same issue can you help me out ,